# Swiping an NFC implant / chip

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Can any Monero wallet be used for swiping an NFC chip? I currently use Mycelium for swiping an NFC implanted chip. After inputting the BIP38 passphrase, I can spend funds.

Can any Monero wallet be used to do the same?